# How to use one username for multiple submit buttons?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I'd like to use one box for username input, then have multiple submit buttons below that will use the username entered above.

Is there some way to store the username as a variable so it will be included in the $post for each of the submit buttons?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="updateDTEST.php" method="post">
Username(Email Address): <input type="text" name="username" /><br />

<p>DT Usage allowed/not allowed</p>

<div align="left">
<select name="status">
<option value=0>Allowed</option>
<option value=1>Revoked</option>
</select>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit me!" />

<p>Add translations to customer</p>

<select name="addtranslations">
<option value=0>Add 0 translations</option>
<option value=2000>Add 2,000 translations</option>
<option value=12000>Add 12,000 translations</option>
<option value=30000>Add 30,000 translations</option>
<option value=80000>Add 80,000 translations</option>
</select>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit me!" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why use 2 forms pointing to only one php file?

Comment: Thank you, its because of lack of experience.  Corrected above.

Comment: The **form** owns all the widgets enclosed within it. All the 'submit' button does is tell the form to send the widget information to the 'action' url in the **form**. You can have multiple 'submit' buttons with different values that the target script can then work out what you want to do. sigh, which is what the answer says.

Comment: At this point, if I wanted to run a MySQL query for one of the options, can you show me how I would ignore the option for the other submit button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a single form. Only the clicked submit button will be successful, so use check for its name/value pair in the post data to see which select you should pay attention to.

Comment: At this point, if I wanted to run a MySQL query for one of the options, can you show me how I would ignore the option for the other submit button?

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) { ... } else { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You can leave your form as it is. Just see if the button is set and read corresponding value.

Example:

```
    //read always
    $username = $_POST['username'])

    if(isset($_POST['submit1'))
        $status = $_POST['status'])
    else if(isset($_POST['submit2'))
        $addtranslations = $_POST['addtranslations'])
```